# regexp global match returns different result javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote this function:

```
function validateName(name) {
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/gim;
    console.log("@@ name = ", name);
    console.log("typeof(re) = ", typeof(re));
    console.log("test returns = %s,re = ", re.test(name),re);
    console.log("test returns = %s,re = ", re.test(name),re);
    console.log("test returns = %s,re = ", re.test(name),re);
    return (re.test(name));
}
```

When I call it with name = "user fifteen" I get:

```
@@ name =  user fifteen
typeof(re) =  object
test returns = true,re =  /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/gim
test returns = false,re =  /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/gim
test returns = true,re =  /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/gim
```

So as you can see, sometimes I get true and some false. I noticed that this happens because of a global match flag, but I cannot understand why.
Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: *As with exec() (or in combination with it), test() called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.* Source mdn